# Is a database the right choice for data storage for my C# application?

Tags: c#, database, data-storage

I am developing a C# application and want to be sure I choose the best choice for data storage that fits these specs.

The program can have a infinite amount of data, but that data will only be used by a single user that is using the application. Each time the application is closed, I need to save the data, and it needs to be loaded in when the application is started.

I have looked at databases, but am unsure as to which would be best suited for my needs. Also, I wonder if I need a database at all given the above specs, maybe I should just use a binary file/XML file implementing serialization and deserialization.

Point me in the right direction please!

Thanks,
OC

***EDIT: One important factor I forgot to include is the necessity to allow one user to save all the entries he/she entered and export it to an external file that can be easily shared between applications/users.***

Comment: Perhaps sharing what your application is about can help us put forth more appropriate suggestions.

Comment: It depends somewhat on the data you want store. What data do you want to store?

Comment: You need to explain how the saved data is to be used? Do you need all of it when the application is running? Just a subset? Do you need to query it?

Comment: Yes a database is the right place to store data.  I believe you are trying to figure out what type of database.  Flat file? Relational? Object? XML? And so on and so forth...

Comment: My application will allow the user to enter customer data. Name, phone number, address, date joined, etc. Its basically data entry for customer information, and then provides functionality to find and display customer subsets based on search options.

Comment: Do you have the memory for an infinite amount of data?  Are you just loading it in and saving it, no working with the data, outside of the program? Then an xml or JSON file would be fine.

Comment: There wouldn't be any interaction with the data outside of the application. The application would be the only one manipulating the data.

Comment: As said before, you need to provide more information.

What is the nature of the data, and how do you need to access it?  How long does the program run?  How much of the data will be accessed during each run?  How many times will the data be accessed each run?  Are you reading data, writing data or both?  What is the relative volume of reads/writes?  How fast does your application need to be?  Is startup time a consideration?

The answers to these questions are more important than the number of users or the amount of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing more about what your specific application does, it's hard (for us) to say whether a database is the right choice. **However, there are some rules of thumb that you can use to help steer your decision.**

**A database may be a good choice when:**

- The data may be used by multiple users.
- When concurrent activity is possible that must be correctly stored.
- When the data collected does not all need to be loaded into memory at once.
- When you wish to be able to query or report on data in complex ways.
- When you want to have transparency into the data being stored using standard tools.
- When changes are mostly localized rather than requiring the entire datastore to be rebuilt.
- When your data lends itself to a relational (rather than say a hierarchical representation).

**A database may not be the best choice when:**

- You only service a single user.
- There is little concurrent activity, and the entire data model must be recreated when saving changes.
- When there will be very little data, and it will be loaded into memory all at once.
- When you data is hierarchical or difficult to model relationally.
- When your application is document-oriented, and documents (files) will be sent to other users.
- When there is a significant amount of binary data interspersed in the data your storing.
- When you want to avoid dependencies to third party tools or services.
- When the structure of your data model is likely to change frequently.

These are all rules of thumb ... no single condition is going to dictate whether to use a database or not. You must examine all of the considerations, and decide whether using a database will give you sufficient benefit - or not.

In many environments, (such as iPhone, for example) there is a built-in database layer available directly on the platform. There are also tools (like NSCoreData) which help you overcome the Object-Relational Modeling (ORM) impedence mismatch. In such cases, it may make a lot of sense to use a database ever for very simple data storage.

There are also a number of open source data persistence layers (NHiberante, DB4O, and others) that help simplify using a database as a persistence store ... which, if you can use them, can shift the equation in favor of using a database.

A database can substantially simplify the development of your application when you need to support queries or search functionality. Relational databases support a query language (SQL), which moves the effort of identifying and retrieving results from the database much easier. Letting the database do the heavy lifting can be a significant time saver - as databases are specifically designed to perform query operations correctly and efficiently. However, this comes at the cost of a well-designed relational data structure - which you must create.

One significant consideration, is whether users will share the data that they create/consume using your application. If your application is more document oriented (think Word, Excel, Powerpoint), then a file-based serialization model may be more appropriate. If your application's data will not be shared - then a database may make sense.

Another significant factor is how open you want your data to be. Databases store information in well-defined structures (tables), and this makes it easier for you (and your users) to directly access and inspect the data. Storage formats like XML, also allow this, but to a somewhat lesser extent.

Answer (score 4):

A full-blown client/server database like MySQL or SQL Server would probably be overkill for a single user.  But you'd probably get some use from an embedded/file-based engine like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx), especially if you want to do more with the data than just look up single records by ID.  If you did the data storage yourself, you'd have to write loads of code to get records meeting certain criteria, and i all but guarantee you won't do as well at it as the people who do it for a living.

Answer (score 2):

Personally for me its more about the data than the number of users using an application.

Think about your data, is it complex? If you were to actually create a database how big would it be in terms of objects, not the amount of rows... how many tables etc...

Think about the future, although its only one user, the data is still going to increase I presume, and how much data will be saved each time?

The database approach will speed up your development no doubt - and your data will have better integrity than an XML file. I hate using files personally... I've had experiences in the past where data has gone missing etc from the file.

Remember, there is always SQL Compact Edition should you want to keep your resources limited.

Comment: Probably only two tables in terms of objects... a customer object table and a job site object table.

I worry about SQL CE because of the 4gb limit. Granted, that is a lot of data considering I'm not storing anything large, but the app should really allow the user to enter data in for years, without having any problems.

Comment: Since you have concerns about 4gb being exceeded that immediately shows that a database is definelty a viable option. A 4gb XML file would be very slow compared to a 4gb database... I would defo go the DB route, cHao makes some good suggestions on choices

Answer (score 1):

If you implement  your storage functions in a repository 1) 2) , you can start with storing to files, and then moving to a database storage if you later identify a need to do so

1) http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html
2) https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx